# Chrome media query behavior

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries, css-transitions

I'm using the following HTML and CSS code to show a toggle button on mobile devices. Clicking this button opens (or closes) a navigation menu with a height transition:

HTML

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation-main">
    <h1 class="menu-toggle">Menú</h1>
    <div class="menu-container">
        <ul class="nav-menu">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.menu-toggle {
    display: none;
}
.navigation-main {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navigation-main ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 50px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .menu-toggle {
        display: block;
    }

    .navigation-main.toggled .nav-menu {
        max-height: 500px;
    }

    .navigation-main .nav-menu {
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s;
        transition: max-height 0.5s;
    }

}
```

I've checked the code in both IE and Firefox and it works as expected. In Chrome too, but with one issue: the navigation menu temporarily shows up for less than 1 second when reloading the page.

Is this a bug in Chrome or is my code wrong? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: pls create a fiddle.... fiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9CcBR/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what was going on myself. To make this work in Chrome, I have to use the same class (**.navigation-main .nav-menu**) to refer to the navigation menu inside and outside the media query on the CSS file.

```
.menu-toggle {
    display: none;
}
.navigation-main {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navigation-main .nav-menu {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 50px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .menu-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navigation-main.toggled .nav-menu {
        max-height: 500px;
    }
    .navigation-main .nav-menu {
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s;
        transition: max-height 0.5s;
    }
}
```